# How to draw linear layout with curve shape in android

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

i want to design linear layout with curve shape,can you please help how to design those types 
     types of layout in android  please give guide to create custom shapes in android, i googled in net but i didnt found any code regarding curve shape, please  help me  ,please  check the above image

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#B1BCBE" />
    <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
    <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
</shape>
```

thank you in advance

Comment: you cannot do that using xml, use ShapeDrawable with a custom Shape object

Comment: can you please provide any reference

Comment: sure,  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable.html#ShapeDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.shapes.Shape)

Comment: Thanks for your support.. let me check once.....